# SQL Server need required output

Tags: sql-server

I  have a table which is represented below:

```
Country_ID | Country_name
-----------+-------------
    1      | India
    2      | Srilanka
    3      | South Africa
    4      | Australia
```

I now need a query that will present this data as below:

```
Match ID | Match Details
---------+---------------------------
    1    | India V/s Srilanka
    2    | India V/s South Africa
    3    | India V/s Australia
    4    | Srilanka V/s South Africa
    5    | Srilanka V/s Australia
    6    | South Africa V/s Australia
```

Comment: Please be more clear!!

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to self join table with higher IDs

```
select
    row_number() over (order by a.country_id, b.country_id)
    , a.country_name + ' v/s ' + b.country_name
from
    myTable a
    join myTable b on a.country_id < b.country_id
```

Comment: This answer will accomplish the result